# EntityFramework: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory'

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to run my application on another machine and am getting the following error:

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
>   I've been trying to figure out what the issue might be, my configuration looks like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RTIDBModel" connectionString="myConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="RTIEmailServer" connectionString="server=smtp.Gmail.com;user id=myEmailService;password=123MyPassword;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The application works fine on my PC when running the exe directly, but when I move the application files, dlls, and config file to a server it gives this error.

I am using a DBContext class to set the connection string directly:

```
public class RtiContext : DbContext
{
        public RtiContext():base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RTIDBModel"].ConnectionString)
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

     .........

}
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this Exception?

Exception Details:

```
ExceptionMessage: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
StackTrace:    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderFactoryExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultInvariantNameResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.OrderByDescending[TSource,TKey](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector)
   at RTI.DataBase.Model.Repositories.SourceRepository.GetAllSources()
```

I am referencing the following dlls:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Web.dll
```

Comment: does the other computer have all of the dependencies? (nuget packages, etc.)

Comment: I migrated all dll's from my release bin over to the install directory on the new machine. I tested this in a remote folder on my desktop with the same dlls and exe.

Comment: You know what, you are right. I just checked my references and I am using a dll that is outside of the release folder! That doesnt seem to resolve the issue though. Copying the external dlls does not solve the problem.

Comment: Also `Copy Local` is set to true, so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Are you copying these from the bin folder? If so, publish to a local folder and make a quick comparison of everything msbuild puts out.